# ganymed-ssh-2 を使った ネットワーク機器へのsshログインについて

Tags: java

はじめまして。

踏み台となるサーバーへの`ssh port 22123`(IPv4)でログインを行い、その後、ルータへのsshログイン(IPv6)を行う際、

```
Connection conn2 = new Connection(hostname2,22123);
conn.connect();
```

にて

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException:xxxxx.xx.jp
```

のエラーが出ます。

※ルーターは、YAMAHA RTX810 や NEC IX2215です

コマンドラインからのログインはできるのですが、ganymed-ssh-2 ライブラリからの接続ができないようです。　踏み台サーバーへのganymed-ssh-2 ライブラリからの接続は問題ありません。
おそらくIPv6でのコネクトに失敗しているのかと考えます。
ご教授いただけますか？

どうぞ、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Javaのプログラムにプロキシーの設定が追加で必要ということはないですか？

Answer (score 0):

名前解決が問題なのか、ネットワーク的な問題なのか(ファイアーウォールとか)切り分けるために、ホスト名ではなく、IPアドレスでの接続をためされるのはいかがでしょうか？

そのつぎは環境が赦せば、ネットワークあまり誉められたやり方ではないですが、personalファイルを切ってみる。例えばプロセスごとに接続先を限定している場合、この方法でわかります。